# Getting all events occurring on a certain date

Tags: shopify, orders

I am trying to get orders from Shopify's API. I have a problem with one scenario: Suppose that one customer makes an order on 2018-04-03 and then requests a refund on 2018-04-25.  I make an API call to get all the orders for 2018-04-03.  Then for that day, I get all my orders with their corresponding refunds even if they are made on other days.  On the other hand, if I make an API call for 2018-04-25, the refund action doesn't appear in the results.  In order to see the refund, I would need to have made an API call for 2018-04-03.  How can I get all the events that actually occurred on a certain day, like the reports I download from Shopify platform?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of crawling the order API by date to try to figure out the refund dates. I will recommend having a webhook on order refund if you can store the payload in a database then you can sort it by date.